# Все о фигах

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Вопрос, в общем-то праздный, но мне интересно: что было первично - фига как фрукт или фига как комбинация из пальцев? Что в честь чего названо и откуда, собственно, взялось название?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фига (инжир, плод фигового дерева) заимствован в 18 веке из польского языка, от др.-нем. figa, восходящего к латинскому ficus.

Фига (кукиш) - исконное, фразеологическая калька с французского языка показывать фигу - faire la fugue.

Итак, Фиг, фига — плоды фигового дерева. Фиг, фига — неприличный жест (то же что и шиш, кукиш, дуля), эвфемизм более грубого ругательства. (Фигня — то же что и бессмыслица). Плутарх считал, что "фиговый лист походит на мужской половой член". В греко-римской традиции, действительно, фиговый лист имеет фаллический смысл, и посвящен Дионису (Вакху).

Также:
 Исследователи утверждают, что плод которым Ева сооблазнила Адама, был не яблоком, а плодом с дерева фикус. Неудивительно, что мы часто называем это дерево смоковницей. Плоды этого дерева действительно приятно смаковать.

В тёплых странах люди очень любят плоды этого дерева, которое они называют "инжир". Англичание называют его "Fig Tree"("Фиговое дерево"), в нашей литературе мы встречаем его под названием „смоковница”, а в быту чаще зовём его по-научному, фикусом. Фикус часто можно встретить в офисах и в квартирах, — небольшое деревце с красивыми кожистыми листьями.

Интересную информацию и фотографии фигового дерева можно посмотреть по ссылке

http://malamant.livejournal.com/97506.html

Comment: Смак и смоква - не родственны.  
первое - от польского смак (вкус), второе - от готского smakka - фига.  

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-12333.htm  
http://fasmer-dictionary.info/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/12422/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA

Answer (score 0):

Как-то не совсем я с Плутархом согласен... Да и фигура из 3х пальцев - фига напоминает именно плод фиги - инжир.
Да и  "фикус" с фиговым деревом (инжир) - это совершенно разные растения. Погуглите хотя бы изображения.